# clean up ugly topology

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I recently found a free Kitbashing kit on gumroad but when i import the .obj file on blender 2.81, all the object are tri or simply unusable like in the example below.
I know that this pack was meant to be used on fusion 369 or 3DSMAX but is it really necessary to use these 2 ?

Do you have an idea why this is made like this ? Is it a importation mistake on my part ?
I've tried to use the blender inbuilt tri to quad but to no effect...
any idea ?

anyway thanks you for your time.

ps: english is not my first language so sorry if some sentence are a bit wonky

link to the orginal pack on gumroad : https://gumroad.com/olegushenok#WagY
[image: unusable topology]

Comment: "*Do you have an idea why this is made like this ?*" Because it is free

Comment: If the model is a hard surface model, not having quads isn't a big deal, provided all the faces and normals are clean. You only need quads when the mesh is being deformed. You get results like that after using boolens to make cutouts.

Answer (score 2):

Select object in Edit mode, press Ctrl + F > Tris to Quads, and set the Max Face Angle and Max Shape Angle to 179 in the tool options.

Go to Object Data Properties > Geometry Data and click Clear Custom Split Normal Data

And finally, In the same tab, under Normals drop down menu, click Auto Smooth

That should take care of it, hope this helps